Why is my code subtitles still overlaping even after tight_layout()?

I tried looking it up but I am pretty new to coding and couldn't figure out, in all the examples I found the subtitles would stop overlapping after tight_layout. I am writing an anime code that shows the how the genre affects the rating. I want to see if there is any correlation or no correlation.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post code as image. It needs to be in text format. Please also provide reproducible test data (in this case, the text of your x tick labels).  There is a help center if you need more information about how to post questions at StackOverflow.

You can rotate the labels 90 degrees:
plt.xticks(rotation=90)



The tight_layout() function doesn't always handle long text or a large number of labels. It tries to adjust the layout to make it as tight as possible. You can try to manually adjust the subplot parameters. For example:
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)


adding space at the bottom won't fix the problem here (overlapping x-axis labels), unless you also do something to space them out (e.g. rotate them)
